# Linq Query return error .An explict conversion is exist

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

I am working on linq query . I have an table called tblUsers and its got column name username , password , reattamp and isLocked . With the linq query i am checking the username and password then if the username account is locked i want to return false otherwise if the user account is unlocked and username and password is correct then i want to method returns true .. I got following errors when i complile the query .

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) HalifaxWCFProject
```

Here is my code in ADO.NET and working fines ...

```
 public bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                var result = false;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(userLogin.Password, "SHA1");
                SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userLogin.Username);
                SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {


                        int RetryAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RetryAttempts"]);
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["AccountLocked"]))
                        {
                            result = false;
                        }
                        else if (RetryAttempts == 1)
                        {
                            result = false;
                        }
                        else if (RetryAttempts > 1)
                        {
                            int AttemptsLeft = (4 - RetryAttempts);
                            result = true;

                        }

                        else if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Authenticated"]))
                        {
                            result = true;
                        }
                    }


                }
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Here is my code linq ..

```
 public bool AuthenticateUser1(UserLogin userLogin)
        {
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities db = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {

                var exceeded = false;
                var totalRetries = -1;
                var attamp = from X in db.tblUsers
                             where X.Username == userLogin.Username
                             select X;

                if (attamp.Any())
                {
                    if (attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.HasValue)
                    {
                        totalRetries = attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts;//Error on this line 
                        exceeded = totalRetries > 4;
                    }
                }
                return exceeded;

            }
        }
```

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function such as SHA-1 is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, It looks like `RetryAttempts` is nullable int. Your code is trying to set it to an int variable.

You can either change your variable to nullable int

```
int? totalRetries=null;
```

Or fix the code to include a null check and if it is not null, read the `Value` property

```
if (attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.HasValue)
{
    totalRetries = attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.Value;
}
```

Code can be further simplified using C# 6 null conditional operator. You actually do not need the `totalRetries` variable as it is a temp variable to derive the value of the boolean variable `exceeded` and that is what your method returns.

```
bool exceeded=false;

var attamp = db.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName == userLogin.Username);

if (attamp?.RetryAttempts != null)
{
    exceeded = attamp.RetryAttempts.Value> 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much but i am not getting expected result

Comment: What you mean , you are not getting expected result ? Your question was about a compile error and the code posted in the answer should solve that. See the second part of my answer. You actually do not even need that variable.

Comment: can you please check the ADO.NET code and this code i am trying to convert to linq but its not giving right out put

Comment: The code i posted will return true if the RetryAttempt column has a non nullable value for that user and it is more than 4, else it will return false. You probably want to include the password check as well.

Comment: its not counting the re attampt into sql databse

Comment: what you mean **into sql database** ?

Comment: when i invock this method with wrong username and password , the re attampt should stored count from 1 to untill 4 in database . if user enter right usrname and password wiht 4 attamt then the colunm values database will be null

Answer (score 0):

you can't store the value of type `int?` to a variable of type `int` because there is simply no way to represent *null* as an integer hence the error; to fix the compiler error, you can do something like:

```
totalRetries = attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.Value;
```

or:

```
totalRetries = attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts ?? totalRetries;
```

Answer (score 0):

`RetryAttempts` appears to be a nullable int (`int?`). Did you try this?

```
if (attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.HasValue)
{
    totalRetries = attamp.FirstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.Value; 
    exceeded = totalRetries > 4;
}
```

You can read more about nullable types here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Comment: I am not getting expecting result ?

Comment: Did you get a different error? What result did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: I am expecting if user enter wrong username and password 4 times then the user account will locked and access will rescrited otherwise if user enter correct username and password with in 4 times then re attampt count will null and redirect to another page

Comment: I don't see the code where RetryAttempts is increased, or AccountLocked is set. Is it possible there's an issue in that code somewhere? Do you have a database row that has RetryAttempts as 5 or above? In your original code I see `int AttemptsLeft = (4 - RetryAttempts);` but `AttemptsLeft` is not used anywhere.

Comment: what will the correct linq quey for this above ado.net ?